# app.blog() vs app.initialize() phonegap Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am working on my first app using phonegap and jquery mobile. I saw a sample code which had this bit in it app.blog() in index.html but have no idea what that does.

I have seem app.initialize() used in many other samples and seen few explanations on it so just wondering if app.blog is an actual command.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

none of those are "real" commands, they are basically telling your app what to run first through index.html with application starting.  so they can be anything you want, as long as they match your javascript code.

Comment: Thanks Kangaroo, I just realized that too :)